# getAttribute in prototype but throws undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm facing a very weird problem in my browser: I have a HTMLElement `elt` that is an image, but `elt.getAttribute` is undefined although `elt.__proto__` contains a `getAttribute` method.

I checked many things:

```
elt.nodeType             => 1
elt.__proto__            => HTMLImageElement {click: function, getAttribute: function, setAttribute: function, removeAttribute: function, getAttributeNode: function…}
elt.__proto__.getAttribute => function getAttribute() { [native code] }
elt.getAttribute         => undefined
elt.setAttribute         => function setAttribute() { [native code] }
elt.getAttributeNS       => function getAttributeNS() { [native code] }
elt.getAttributeNode     => function getAttributeNode() { [native code] }
elt.getAttributeNodeNS   => function getAttributeNodeNS() { [native code] }
typeof elt               => object
```

Any idea where this might come from ? I have no idea where this comes from.

Comment: provide your codes to check

Comment: There's just too much code. I should transform my question in: "why on earth can someone do `object.setAttribute = undefined` when object is a dom element"

Answer (score 1):

I tried the simplest possible scenario:

```
<img name="elt" src="...">


<script>

    var elt = document.images.namedItem("elt");

    alert(elt.getAttribute);     // function getAttribute() { [native code] }   
    alert(elt.getAttribute == elt.__proto__.getAttribute);     // true

</script>
```

and I get what expected which means that the prototype chain works.
My suggestion is to check the output of:

```
elt.getAttribute == elt.__proto__.getAttribute
```

if they are not equal as it seems in your case then you did something which broke the prototype chain.
I can simulate you scenario as follows:

```
<img name="elt" src="...">


<script>

    var elt = document.images.namedItem("elt");

    alert(elt.getAttribute);     // function getAttribute() { [native code] }   
    alert(elt.getAttribute == elt.__proto__.getAttribute);     // true

    elt.getAttribute = undefined;

    alert(elt.getAttribute == elt.__proto__.getAttribute);     // false

</script>
```

Hence what I think is that elt.getAttribute has been defined somewhere in your code and set to 'undefined'.